# RxJava - wait for async task and then call Api

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Trying to get `lastLocation` and once it's done call api. But somehow once location is obtained my api calls always running in `mainThread`, so i'm getting exception:

```
android.io.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

***Here is my location observer:***

```
fun getLocation(): Single<Location> {
        return Single.create<Location> { subscriber ->
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it != null) {
                    subscriber.onSuccess(it)
                } else {
                    subscriber.onError(Exception("No location"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

***Code that does some transformations***

```
val locationObserver = getLocation()
observables.add(locationObserver.flatMap { _ -> sendDataToServer(data)})
```

***Observer***

```
Single.zip(observables) { args1 -> args1 }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({
            Timber.i("Success")

        }, {
            Timber.i("Error %s", observables.size, it.localizedMessage)
            it.printStackTrace()
        })
```

I've set `subscribeOn` so it shouldn't be on `mainThread`, but looks like something missed.

Found that if i will use something like `Single.just("One").flatMap{ ... }` that will work fine and will be executed on non-main thread.

Is there something to do with `getLocation` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `subscribeOn`, `observeOn`, `subscribe`, and transformations matters. Apparently, it's needed to do the transformations, in this case, the `flatMap` *after* specifying the observer thread with `observeOn` to make sure the code is executed in the right thread.

Comment: After subscribe block it’s no longer observable, so you can’t do that. It’s applicable only before subscribe call

Comment: Oh my bad, what if you switch the order of `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`? I used to have a similar problem and changing these orders is what solved it.

Comment: Oh damn, you pointed me in right direction. Please modify your answer to use `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` before `.flatMap{}`

Comment: Glad I did, I have edited the answer, make sure that's what you meant.